# Can you change parameter inside an if statement

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

I'm new to bash, and am asking if I can change the parameter value inside an if statement. However, im getting an error of: `attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=27-26")`

The code i'm running is

```
if (( $1 > 26 ))
then
    let $1="$1-26"
fi

echo $1
```

Comment: Replace `let $1="$1-26"` with `set -- $(($1-26))`.

Comment: `set -- "$(( $1 > 26 ? $1 - 26 : $1 ))" "${@:2}"`